# Closed form expression for $\psi_{e^{\pi}}^{(3)}(1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, mathematica, digamma-function, polygamma

Let $\psi_q(x)$ be the q-DiGamma function defined for a real variable $x>0$ as $$\psi_q(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma_q(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (\Gamma_q(x))$$
where $\Gamma_q(x)$ is the q-Gamma function defined as $$\Gamma_q(x)=(1-q)^{1-x}\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q^{n+x}}$$

**Question** I am looking for a closed form for $$\psi_{e^{\pi}}^{(3)}(1)$$

If anyone could please solve this by hand or mathematica or sage math. I would be highly indebted to you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=qpolygamma%283%2C1%2Cx%29) the expansion at $x=\infty$:

$$\psi_x^{(3)}(1)=\ln^4(x)\left(x^{-1}+9x^{-2}+\dots\right)$$

and these match Oeis [A$001158$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=qpolygamma%283%2C1%2Cx%29) with [divisor $\sigma_v(n)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=divisorsigma%283%2Cn%29) and various theta functions after plugging the sum back in [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ln%28x%29%5E4+sum%5Bdivisorsigma%283%2Cn%29%2Fx%5En%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfty%7D%5D). Use $\vartheta_v(0,x)=\vartheta_v(x)$:

$$\psi_x^{(3)}(1)=\ln^4(x)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sigma_3(n)}{x^n}=\frac{\ln^4(x)}{480}\left(\vartheta_2\left(\frac1{\sqrt x}\right)^8+ \vartheta_3\left(\frac1{\sqrt x}\right)^8+ \vartheta_4\left(\frac1{\sqrt x}\right)^8-2\right)$$

Therefore:

$$\psi_{e^\pi}^{(3)}(1)=\frac{\pi^4}{480}\left(\vartheta_2^8\left(e^{-\frac\pi2}\right)+ \vartheta_3^8\left(e^{-\frac\pi2}\right)+ \vartheta_4^8\left(e^{-\frac\pi2}\right)-2\right)$$

Clicking “more digits” [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=qpolygamma%283%2C1%2Ce%5Epi%29-lim%5Bsum%5Bln%28x%29%5E4+sigma%283%2Cn%29%2Fx%5En%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfty%7D%5D%2Cx-%3Eexp%28pi%29%5D) shows a smaller error each time implying the result is true.

Now use Dedekind $\eta(z)$ identities for $\vartheta_v\left(e^{-\frac\pi2}\right)$ when [$v=2$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta2/03/01/02/0001), [$v=3$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta3/03/01/02/0001/), and [$v=4$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta4/03/01/02/0001/)

$$\psi_{e^\pi}^{(3)}(1)= \frac{\pi^4}{480}\left(\left(2\frac{\eta^2(i)}{\eta\left(\frac i2\right)}\right)^8+\left(\frac{\eta^5\left(\frac i2\right)}{\eta^2\left(i\right)\eta^2\left(\frac i4\right)}\right)^8+\left(\frac{\eta^2\left(\frac i4\right)}{\eta\left(\frac i2\right)}\right)^8-2\right)$$

Using [special values](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function) in terms of $\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)$:

$\eta\left(\frac i4\right)=2\eta(4i)=\frac{\sqrt[4]{\sqrt2-1} \Gamma\left(\frac14\right)}{2^\frac{13}{16}\pi^\frac34},\eta\left(\frac i2\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)}{2^\frac 78\pi^\frac34},\eta(i)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)}{2\pi^\frac34}$

Finally, [substitute](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=pi%5E4%2F480+%28%282+a%5E2%2Fb%29%5E8%2B%28b%5E5%2F%28a%5E2+c%5E2%29%29%5E8%2B%28c%5E2%2Fb%29%5E8-2%29%2Cc%3D%28%E2%88%9A2-1%29%5E%281%2F4%29+gamma%281%2F4%29%2F%282%5E%2813%2F16%29+pi%5E%283%2F4%29%29%2Cb%3Dgamma%281%2F4%29%2F%282%5E%287%2F8%29+pi%5E%283%2F4%29%29%2Ca%3Dgamma%281%2F4%29%2F%282+pi%5E%283%2F4%29%29) and have a form in terms of $\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)$ which has [no elementary closed form](https://oeis.org/A068466). Therefore:

$$\boxed{\psi_{e^\pi}^{(3)}(1)=\frac{11\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)^8}{5120\pi^2}-\frac{\pi^4}{240}}$$

[**shown here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=qpolygamma%283%2C1%2Ce%5Epi%29-%28-64+%CF%80%5E6+%2B+33+%CE%93%281%2F4%29%5E8%29%2F%2815360+%CF%80%5E2%29)

Comment: I am indebted to you for your effort. Thank you. I would really appreciate if a closed form can be found of $\vartheta_v\left(e^{-\frac\pi2}\right)$

Comment: @Anixx Thank you for your edit. One small help please. The link of Dedekind eta function $\eta(z)$ is not working